# Is $\int \operatorname{sn}^2u\,\mathrm du$ really irreducible?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Let $\operatorname{sn}$, $\operatorname{cn}$, $\operatorname{dn}$ be Jacbian elliptic functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/22). According to Greenhill,

> The integrals
> $$\operatorname{sn}^2u,\operatorname{cn}^2u,\operatorname{dn}^2u$$
> **require** for their expression new functions called elliptic integrals of the second kind, such as occur for instance in the rectification of the ellipse.

Can we prove that
$$\int \operatorname{sn}^2u\,\mathrm du,\ldots$$
**cannot** be expressed as a finite composition of elementary functions and elliptic functions? This is equivalent to proving that the *Jacobi epsilon* (https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16#ii) cannot be expressed as a finite composition of elementary and elliptic functions.

You can contrast this with, e.g.,
$$\int \operatorname{sn}(u,k)\,\mathrm du=-\frac{1}{k}\operatorname{artanh}(k\operatorname{cd}(u,k))+C$$
where no elliptic integrals of the second kind appear and where elementary functions and elliptic functions are sufficient.

Comment: For a minute I thought that sn and cn are sine and cosine

Comment: Also posted https://mathoverflow.net/q/458836/454

Comment: good question +1